# font awesome: when use hover::before, the icon disappeared

Tags: css, font-awesome, pseudo-element

I want to hover the icon so it will show the `before` element, but every time I hover it, the icon disappeared, and when I hover the right-half part of the icon, nothing happened. If I change `before` to `after`, it works well.

```css
.container {
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 100px;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
}

.icon:hover::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle icon"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Because `font awesome` uses `.fa-exclamation-circle::before` to display the icon. You're overriding the style with your `.icon:hover::before`

Comment: you want it to turn to black?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add the black background when hovered over.  You can't rest the `content` as that is utilized to display the icon by FontAwesome.

```css
.container {
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 100px;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
}

.icon:hover::before {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle icon"></i>
</div>
```